# Get groups in time series with categorical data in R for use in gts

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data

I have sales data organised in a table with 6 columns (4 for the location and type data, and 2 for the dates and the quantity sold), and 24 rows for each category representing the sales over 24 months (there are 7104 rows, 24 for each of the 296 possibilities I have).

I want to use [hts.gts](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/gts/), but I need to create the group hierarchy and to change the format of the data for that. What would be the best way to do that in R?

Additionally, is there a better way to store this data?

EDIT: Here is how the data looks:

```
   PERIOD              PRODUCT.TYPE       BRAND      SIZE   CITY        VALUE
1: 2012-01             A                  X          100    SOFIA       0.11134739
2: 2012-02             A                  X          100    SOFIA       0.02486429
3: 2012-03             A                  X          100    SOFIA       0.09738088
4: 2012-04             A                  X          100    SOFIA       0.11401330
5: 2012-05             A                  X          100    SOFIA       0.15660395
6: 2012-06             A                  X          100    SOFIA       0.21496220
```

I have a bunch of different products types, each having a different amount of brands and sizes, and which are not all being sold in every city.

Comment: I don't follow your description. Can you please show the first few rows of your data table with column headings?

Comment: I edited my post with the head of the data.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `hts` package, the data input should be an `mts` object. The data above seems a `data.frame` or a `data.table` and you need to convert it to a matrix form that contains 296 columns (due to 296 possibilities) and 24 rows (2-year monthly data). The input looks like the following

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- ts(matrix(rnorm(7104), nrow = 24, ncol = 296), start = c(2012, 1),
          frequency = 12)
```

Because you've got the relevant grouping information, paste the columns `PRODUCT.TYPE`, `BRAND`, `SIZE` and `CITY` together without space using `paste` or `paste0` functions to get a new variable saying `blevels` referring to the bottom-level labels and assign `blevels` to the column names of `dat`.

```
colnames(dat) <- blevels
```

Assuming `blevels` has characters of same length, the argument `characters` in the `gts` function can be used.

```
library(hts)
datgts <- gts(dat, characters = c(1, 1, 3, 5))
```

Rob's post you mentioned above gives the detailed explanation on how to construct a `gts` object, if there's more complicated structure.

Hope this helps to get it work. :)

Comment: The problem is that my products, brands, etc. have different lengths, so I can't just paste them together.

Comment: Using `characters` is the quickest way to create a gts object, but the labels must be of the same lengths. The other way around is that you trim some of your labels for products and brands to the same lengths if trimmed version preserves all the information. Alternatively, you'd like to try `groups` argument to create your own grouping matrix instead of `characters` doing it for you.

Comment: Hi Earo Wang and Pafnouti. :)
I'm only 1-month old with RStudio. I was following your session, until I got stuck on the matrix creation. I have successfully created a matrix, however the values were rnorm-generated. How do I replace those values with the original series? Thanks a lot. :)